# Should I move function from controller to a service, but then having to use rootScope instead of scope, for the sake of unit testing?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

I have this project where I can have the function in the controller or service. However, it will be better for the function to be in a service just for the sake of unit testing, but then I have to bind my variables to the global scope. Is it worth the trade off?

Comment: this question doesn't make any sense.  Why would having a function in a service require global variables?  Sounds like you have some terminology confusion.

Comment: @Claies Variables that are binded to the rootScope. I want to pass in variables to the function from the controller. I would just return the function.

Comment: right, and why wouldn't you access the service from the controller? using a service doesn't mean you have to use `$rootScope`...  without some code explaining what you mean, it's still not clear why one would cause the other.

Comment: You cannot access regular $scope in the service though. I am passing in the service to the controller so it can be invoked.

Comment: why do you need to access `$scope` from a service at all?  It doesn't sound like your service is designed properly.  Accessing `$rootScope` from a service isn't going to make the service work better, or make it more testable.  In fact, using `$rootScope` at all is an anti-practice, and bad code smell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it makes sense to move it to the service, then you definitely should. As far as binding it to the $rootScope as an alternative to $scope because you are moving it, perhaps you should instead consider returning the results of the service function that the controller can bind to. For example:

```
.factory('YourService', function() {
    return {
        //needs to be theFunction: function theFunction, not theFunction:theFunction
        theFunction: function theFunction(param1, ...) {
            var results = ... some complicated logic ...
            return results;
        }
    };
});

.controller('YourController', ['$scope', 'YourService', function($scope, YourService) {
    ...

    $scope.results = YourService.theFunction($scope.param1, ...);

    ...
}]);
```

Or if the function performs some async functionality, then return a promise and do something like this in the controller:

```
.controller('YourController', ['$scope', 'YourService', function($scope, YourService) {
    ...

    YourService.theFunction($scope.param1, ...).then(function(results) {
        $scope.results = results;
    }, function(err) {...handle errors});

    ...
}]);
```

Staying clear of the $rootScope by doing something like this will make your services even more testable since it will have less dependencies.